# Insert script at login page - Roundcube

Tags: javascript, roundcube

I'm trying to insert that Mcafee Security etiquette into my web page. Mcafee gave me the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js" async> </script>
```

However, it does not appear on my page when I add it.

I'm adding in the `<head>` tag. The page to which I am inserting is in the following location:

```
/home/apache2/old/newmail/skins/george
```

Login.html

Comment: Check the browser's console for errors

Comment: If you are a client, you can contact a certification specialist: https://www.mcafeesecure.com/start

Don't you have to include also some js code? If so, pay attention to the async

Comment: I don't see what is the problem about the location of the file. You are using a cdn. Maybe am I missing something? (to be clarified, so we can help better(

Comment: this worked when i put the full javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the website you are trying to insert it on is registered and currently being used. The script looks at the location.host, here would be `stackoverflow.com`before sending the code to display the actual element.  Note the line with setting the `src` attribute.

```
try{
    var v=document.createElement("script");
    v.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    v.setAttribute("src","//cdn.ywxi.net/js/host-loader.js?h="+location.host);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(v)
}catch(e){};
```

You can test this by going to the website `cdn.ywxi.net/js/host-loader.js?h=<YOUR HOST HERE>` and confirm there is JavaScript sent back.

Comment: yep , so i move to cdn.ywxi ... and debug the full code and insert at login.html page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code into

`/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail-1.0.1/skins/larry/includes/links.html`